# Where can I find Symfony default controller

Tags: symfony

Where can I find the class/function of

```
FrameworkBundle:Template:template
```

In Symfony 3 and how does this namespace is working

It is used as the default controller
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/render_without_controller.html

```
acme_privacy:
path: /privacy
defaults:
    _controller: FrameworkBundle:Template:template
    template:    static/privacy.html.twig
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This special controller (`Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Template`) and method action can be found on oficial github `symfony\symfony` package:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/TemplateController.php

Under `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Following the Controller Naming Pattern
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#controller-string-syntax

```
 FrameworkBundle -> TemplateController -> templateAction
```

as @felipsmartins mention it is at (Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Template)

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/TemplateController.php